# Overwrite css properties for .ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay-image

Tags: jquery, flexbox, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have responsive youtube videos: width:350% and height:100vh.

Unfortunately for desktop the placeholder images are stretched 350% width, while in mobile they looks great. I want to keep the stretch for desktop that made youtube videos like full-screen but placeholder images look horrible.

[mobile site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRZtt.jpg)

[desktop site](https://koreanwave.cloudaccess.host/)

I am unable to overwrite .ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay-image to have a fix.

I have this code to replace youtube placeholder that works great...but how to adapt it to overwrite .ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay-image css properties:

Sorry, I am newbie.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="source">url(&quot;this is your URL&quot;)</div>
<div id="match"></div>


string = $(".ytp-cued-thumbnail-overlay").css('background-image');
$("#img1").attr('src', string.match(/.*url\(['|"]([^)]*)['|"]\)/i));
```

Overwrite css here:

```
string = $("#source").text();
$("#match").text(string.match(/.*url\(['|"]([^)]*)['|"]\)/i)[1]);

#source, #match { display:inline-block;border:1px solid #aaa;padding:10px; } // width:100% !important;
#source:before { color:#aaa;content:'source: '; }
#match:before { color:#aaa;content:'match: ';}
```

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Maciek,

This is what I did to fix the problem with YT placeholders.

[Live Demo here:](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GF0CHUNBYGL4)

For mobile I just reset "my_container_wrapper" to its original values and iframe to 100%.

I found issues with Soundcloud placeholder too... so sad, I added a css class to each embedded Soundcloud. I wish to find a way to set it globally.

```
.soundcloud_iframe{ min-width: 100vw; min-height:100vh; left: 0%;}
```

Check my website:

[mobile site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZkKK.jpg)

[desktop site](https://koreanwave.cloudaccess.host/)

Answer (score 0):

Just a blind shot but you can try adding `min-width:100%; max-width:100%; min-height:100%; max-height:100%; width:100%; height:100%;` either to the thumbnail element or to the container, then in the web inspector try switching those properties on and off to verify what works best.